# Connectivity Tunnel including IAM security in python with paramiko

Tags: python, authentication, ssh, paramiko, fibers

I am already using python for connecting to remote server through jump server with paramiko and executing SSH commands through python in jupyter notebook which resides on user's **local machine**.
Now, I have following connectivity challenge where ultimately I want to reach Server-B through different authentication channels which is below:

`Python SSH commands in jupyter` > `VPN`> `Server-A`> `NetGuard with IAM security`> `RDP server`> `server-B`

could you please suggest me how to solve this issue and is this possible through `paramiko` or any other library to connect through `IAM` based security feature and `can we authenticate this NetGuard using authenticator app code in python/paramiko`?

[image: Connectivity Tunnel Image]

Please ask me if you need further assistance for understanding.